# What does the label "triaged" mean on TensorFlow issues?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm interested to make some contributions to TensorFlow in future. I saw that some labels have "contributions welcome" and "triaged" at the same time. Can someone explain to me what "triaged" means?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/labels/triaged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's part of our internal process, to help us make sure we look through all of the Github issues that the community submits. Having the label is an indication that we've seen the issue, and usually means we've marked it as something we'd welcome help with, assigned it to a team member to be worked on, or taken some other action to handle it appropriately.

Does that help?